# Use of "noextraspace" affects title page layout for APA 7

Tags: spacing, apa-style, section-titles, apa7

I'm writing an academic paper on Overleaf using APA 7 format. I inserted the *"noextraspace"* class option, which removes the extra spacing between headers, paragraphs, etc., to more closely align with APA 7 standards.

However, it removes the required extra spacing between the title and author on the title page.

How do I add one double-spaced blank line beneath the title? I've tried many commands. I suspect that the template generates the title page but I can't edit it through Overleaf.

*Correct format*
[image]

*My title page*
[image]

Find example code below to replicate my issue.

```
\documentclass[stu,12pt]{apa7}
%Adding "noextraspace" to document class line above fixes spacing between headings and paragraphs. However, it removes the necessary extra space between title and author on the title page.

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\title{Experiments in Cognition}

\author{H. Granger}
\affiliation{University}
\course{PSYC 355}
\professor{Professor S. Snape}
\duedate{January 1, 2022}

\abstract{\lipsum1}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum2
\section{Methods}
\lipsum4
\subsection{Participants}
\lipsum5
\end{document}
```

Comment: I realized that this problem also affected the reference page (first reference is too far beneath the page title). 
In the end I removed the "noextraspace" class and MacGyvered the spacing between headings and paragraphs by using commands such as \vspace{-0.3cm} to remove extra line space.
Would still value a workaround for my original problem that allows me to use "noextraspace" in the \documentclass preamble line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally undo the option for `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass[stu,12pt,noextraspace]{apa7}
%Adding "noextraspace" to document class line above fixes spacing between headings and paragraphs. However, it removes the necessary extra space between title and author on the title page.

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\title{Experiments in Cognition}

\author{H. Granger}
\affiliation{University}
\course{PSYC 355}
\professor{Professor S. Snape}
\duedate{January 1, 2022}

\abstract{\lipsum1}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\saveddef@noextraspace\def@noextraspace
\let\def@noextraspace\undefined
\maketitle
\let\def@noextraspace\saveddef@noextraspace
\makeatother

\lipsum2
\section{Methods}
\lipsum4
\subsection{Participants}
\lipsum5
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @david-carlisle, your workaround solved my problem. I have also reached out to the author of the template, since an update would be the long term way to correct this.

Comment: The creator of the APA 7 package released an update on January 18, 2022, that address the problem described in the question.
https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2452.1642538160.10251.ctan-ann@ctan.org

Comment: @ErAvE thanks for the update